# Did David utter an unnecessary oath?

Tags: king-david, nedarim-shevuot, samuel-shmuel-book-of

In 1 Shmuel 25 Avigail persuades David not to execute his plan to kill Naval and Naval's household. After David acquiesces to her plea he then continues in pasuk 34 to swear (see commentaries such as Metzudat David who explain this is an oath) by the name of God that had she not interceded he would have killed out the whole of Naval's household by morning. I am trying to understand the nature of this oath. What was the necessity for David to make an oath, about something he would have done but will no longer be doing, using the name of God? Is this in violation of Shemot 20:7?

Comment: Are you assuming that it would be a problem if he did that? Maybe that should be part of the question.

Comment: FYI - some interesting background from the Gemara in Megillah https://www.sefaria.org/Megillah.14a.22?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

Comment: A righteous person is allowed to swear in G-d's name.

Comment: Maybe by saying that he meant to make a *shevuah* that he wouldn't kill them. "Before it was like that, now it's like this."